# How to use limitTo filter dynamically to display long texts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I have a directive that generate a data-table.

I have to make a column in this data-table show a limit text, so I want a link that  show the full text when I click on the link. Something like 'more or less'.

I have this code below. I believe the code is right, I get this solution [here](https://nicholasmandel.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/limit-characters-displayed-in-text-with-angular/)

```
<tbody  ng-init="limit = 10; showed = false">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in dataPaginated | orderBy: orderDefinitions">
                <td ng-repeat="column in columns | orderBy: 'id'" ng-style="{ 'white-space' : (column.nowrap) ? 'nowrap !important' : 'normal' }"
                    ng-show="column.checked">


                    <div ng-if="column.isRichText">
                          <!--  I've already tried initiate the limit and showed variables here --> 
                        <div >
                            {{ row[column.mapProperty] | limitTo : limit  }}
                            <a ng-if="column.isRichText" ng-show="row[column.mapProperty].length > limit" href
                            ng-click="limit = row[column.mapProperty].length ; showed = true">more</a> 
                            <a ng-if="column.isRichText" ng-show="showed" href
                            ng-click=" limit=10"> less</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-if="">
                        <!--  When the column isn't richText -->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But it isn't working, The link `more` appear and when I click the limit is updated but the full text and the link `less` is not showed.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: Sorry, Now I completed  the question

Comment: Might be due to `ng-if` creates a child scope. Create a plunker that reproduces the basic issue. I think if you made `limit` into an object instead it might work

Comment: You're right the problem is `ng-if` thanks